# Need help changing search results URL to something which can be bookmarked

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I hope someone can help me with this.

Currently when someone does a search on my website, the page that is returned has the URL:

> http://www.dublinjobs.ie/main/index.
>
> (Let's call this "the search results URL").

If you scroll to the bottom of the page you will see the pagination URLs use the form

> http://www.dublinjobs.ie/main/index/2/basic/php/0/relevance/all/0/0/20/0/0/0/0/0/0/0.
>
> (Let's call this "the pagination URL").

Is there some way I can change my website so the search results URL has a similar format to the pagination URL?

I need to to fix this because currently the search results URL cannot be bookmarked or emailed to someone as it is unspecific.

I'm guessing the solution is some sort of internal URL rewrite but I am not sure how to do this.

Thank you for your assistance.

EDIT: I don't want to just use a GET instead of a POST as I want to be able to control the URL layout.

Answer (score 0):

Even your pagination URL doesn't include **search term**. What you need is to include search keywords in the URL itself to make it unique which can be bookmarked or shared.

Most likely you're using `method="POST"` in your search form which needs to change to: `method="GET"`.

Note that it will make your URL like:

```
http://www.dublinjobs.ie/main/index?search=keyword
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The pagination URL does include the search term, e.g. "PHP".

Comment: Then show/post your current rules that are forming both search and paginations URLs

Comment: The rules are complicated. Do you know of a way I can simply rewrite the URL to what I want it to be?

Comment: Yes you can rewrite the URL but your search URL doesn't even have search term so rule cannot magically insert it. Rewrite rules need to have all the information in source URL to write it to target URL

Comment: Ah thank you. That's interesting, I wasn't aware of that. So if I changed it to a GET I could then rewrite the URL as the source URL has more information.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have a dirty hack fix.

I am using a header redirect in my PHP code to send them to the URL I want after doing my processing.